# using async await in class to assign properties but returns null

Tags: javascript, class, promise, async-await

I have a class with `_code` set to `null` from the start then making a request to an `url` to get the result.

Somehow I am after assigning the class's property code with the result still gives me null though.

What am I doing wrong with this?

```
class R {
    constructor() {
        this._code = null;
    }

    get code() {
        return this._code;
    }

    set code(value) {
        this._code = value;
    }

    async makingRequests(id) {
        await this.requestToGetCode(id);
        // this gives me null
        console.log(this.code, 'this.code in rquest');
    }

    async requestToGetCode(id) {
        await request(url, async (error, response, body) => {
            if (body !== 'found_no_results') {
                switch (response.statusCode) {
                    case 200:
                        this.code = await JSON.parse(body);
                        // this does give me the proper result though
                        console.log(this.code, 'this.code in requestToGetCode');
                        break;
                    case 404:
                        console.log('page not found');
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            } else {
                console.log(body, id);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

thanks in advance for any help and suggestions.

Comment: Remove the `await` in front of the `JSON.parse`. You should only use this for async calls which `JSON.parse` is not.

Comment: @Mathyn tried that too, doesn't work though

Comment: You need to return a promise from `requestToGetCode`, currently you're returning `undefined` (implicitly) so there's nothing for the caller to await. You can just `return request(/*...*/)` instead of awaiting it.

Comment: @MarkMeyer I did try that before, but I couldnt' find the result `body` returned though :(

Comment: Sorry @Tsuna — I didn't notice you were using the regular `request` library. This doesn't return a promise, it takes a callback. You need promises to work with `async/await`. Something like axios might work better.

Comment: What `request` library are you using?

Comment: @MarkMeyer no worries, guess I should go with axios instead then.  Totally forgot about `request` might have such problem :|

Comment: @zero298     `"request": "^2.88.0"`

Comment: Or just use [`request-promise`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise) which is supposed to be almost a drop-in replacement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments the Request library does not return a promise and instead works with a callback. You could use a library like [request-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise) to work around this. However if you do not want to do this for some reason this answer might help you.

To be able to use async/await with the Request library you need to manually wrap the call in a Promise.

```
async requestToGetCode(id) {
    await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        request(url, (error, response, body) => {
            if (body !== 'found_no_results') {
                switch (response.statusCode) {
                    case 200:
                        this.code = JSON.parse(body);
                        // this does give me the proper result though
                        console.log(this.code, 'this.code in requestToGetCode');
                        resolve();
                        break;
                    case 404:
                        console.log('page not found');
                        reject('Not found');
                        break;
                    default:
                        // Reject all other cases
                        reject('Error');
                        break;
                }
            } else {
                // Reject as we do not receive the correct response
                console.log(body, id);
                reject('Error');
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Essentially we are creating a new Promise here which will do the request for us. In the request callback we then call `resolve` or `reject` depending on the result.

Comment: I changed to using `axios` instead so I didn't try this out.  But I do believe this would work as what was suggested and advised.  Will mark you as answer. :D